# Error converting string date format 'yymmdd' to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

If I execute the following query in SQL Server everything is fine:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '580112', 12)

1958-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

But when I execute this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [ID]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[MiddleName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,CONVERT(datetime, [DateOfBirth],  12)
      ,[address]
      ,[city]
      ,[state]
      ,[zip]
      ,[phoneNumber]
  FROM [dbo].[PF]
GO
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

My data is like this:

```
ID FirstName MiddleName LastName DateOfBirth address city state zip phonenumber
1   100 MARGARET    P   BIGGIO  580112  122 WALTHAM ST  MAYNARD MA          01754 9788971581
```

EDIT:

Other dates is same yymmdd ISO format:

```
DateOfBirth
531000
481023
500700
500200
570518
411100
580112
510100
840800
671200
680605
681216
430600
470701
470330
630206
470600
710914
620800
590100
```

The `DateOfBirth` is VARCHAR, do I have to cast it to something else?

Comment: Have you tried casting it to datetime like : `CONVERT(datetime, cast([DateOfBirth] as datetime),  12)`

Comment: Yes I did: `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: Ok, let me check, I'll revert shortly...

Comment: You can't count on "select top 1" to return the record associated with ID = 1.  What does the smallest and largest value of DateOfBirth look like in your table?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any bad data e.g. 31st Feb, or in a different format e.g. based on your example '120158'

Comment: I'm sure all of my data is in format `yymmdd ISO`

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing it in that format instead of a more intuitive and standard (ISO) one, such as YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: It is an old database, I didn't store it myself unfortunately in this format.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no empty spaces at the end of DateOfBirth values in your table?  What does ,CONVERT(datetime, rtrim([DateOfBirth]),  12) yield?

Comment: `CONVERT(datetime, rtrim([DateOfBirth]), 12)` same: `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`... very strange, could be `VARCHAR(50)` data type (!) the culprit?

Comment: What if you run your select query, but add "WHERE ID = 1"...does that return one result, or throw the same error?

Comment: I think the problem are the erroneus dates like `531000`

Comment: Yes, that would be it lol :)

Comment: Indeed, the dates with 00 day are the problem :-\

Comment: If you use `TRY_CONVERT`, you can get the records that have the issue while still returning correct dates.  They would come back as `NULL`

Comment: I just used your data and I did not experience the same problem. What version of SQL are you running?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2016 or later, try using the `TRY_CONVERT()` function to locate your bad data.

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Also, beware of SQL Server's two digit year behavior: "By default, SQL Server interprets two-digit years based on a cutoff year of 2049. That means that SQL Server interprets the two-digit year 49 as 2049 and the two-digit year 50 as 1950. Many client applications, including those based on Automation objects, use a cutoff year of 2030. SQL Server provides the two digit year cutoff configuration option to change the cutoff year used by SQL Server. "  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: Think I found the problem, when I used this date `531000`, it gives me that error as well. I suppose SQL is having a hard time reading that date...

Comment: 531000 is not a real date - you can't have day 00 of a month.

Comment: Agreed @ChrisHackett, but that's the data he provided in the question. Which means the data is wrong...

Comment: You are right about two digit-years: `101 JOHN A BIGGIO 2048-10-23 00:00:00.000 122 WALTHAM ST MAYNARD MA         01754                                                        `

Comment: Encountered the same problem @bsteo :)

Comment: Now someone write an answer, I don't want to answer myself :)

Comment: Here's how to control the cutoff year: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017 But you will need to know your data before you can set the cutoff year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your data is incorrect.

Using the following it works:

```
declare @tbl as table (ID int primary key identity, FirstName varchar(50), MiddleName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50),DateOfBirth varchar(50),address varchar(50),city varchar(50),state varchar(50),zip varchar(50),phonenumber varchar(50))
insert into @tbl (  FirstName,  MiddleName, LastName, DateOfBirth, address, city, state, zip, phonenumber) values
                (   'MARGARET', 'P',    'BIGGIO','531001','122','WALTHAM ST','MAYNARD MA','01754','9788971581')

select
    [ID]
,   [FirstName]
,   [MiddleName]
,   [LastName]
,   convert(datetime, [DateOfBirth],  12)   DateOfBirth
,   [address]
,   [city]
,   [state]
,   [zip]
,   [phoneNumber]
from @tbl
```

But when the date is changed to `531000`, SQL can't read it.

Correct the data, then your query works.

Answer (score 1):

@bsteo the above issue is coming because date value cannot be 00 that why error is coming see the diff below..

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '500700', 12)

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

same value with 01 date

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '500701', 12)

1950-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

check the difference..